# apt-get update tries to download uncompressed Packages file

Tags: server, apt, maas

I am using a physical server right now. I have installed MAAS and cannot use the `apt-get` function at all. When I type `sudo apt-get update` I get a long string with some things updating and most things returning an error (output for this command at bottom of question). If I type `apt-get install` [any package at all] I get something like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or

is only available from another source

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
```

`ifconfig` returns all the correct information, `eth0` is up and running, I can ping any website I like, I can connect over `ssh`, I can even access the server from my browser on another computer but `apt` won't work for anything. I have tried to reinstall three times with different boot disks and one of those times I even tried using the standard Ubuntu Server and wound up with the exact same problem. Also `apt` is working fine on other computers on the network.

*Stackoverflow* won't let me print out the output for update without 10 reputation and it's too long for a comment so here is the last part of it (the rest is just err [link] packages).

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages
> HttpError404
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
> HttpError404
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

Comment: `Packages` doesn't exist, but `Packages.gz` does. Something seems to be odd with `apt`. Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` through Ubuntu Pastebin, and add a link here?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7843357/

Comment: damn. I appreciate you looking.

Comment: try `apt search vim` + Enter ... for vim editor.

Comment: Did you change any apt config settings? In particular, is *Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order* set to "uncompressed";... ? You can dump the current apt config with `apt-config dump`

Comment: I havent changed anything and wont have access to the server again until Monday. But when i can I'll look into that,  thank you.